# Avalondock document tab repositioning

Tags: wpf, avalondock

Avalondock repositions document tabs when one is resizing the document panel. See images below

[image: Tab position before resize]
[image: Tab position after resize]

Can anyone please tell me how Avalondock manages the order of its tabs? Where can I find this logic (for the repositioning for instance) in the source code of Avalondock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out in the meanwhile.. it is the ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize) method from DocumentPaneTabPanel which is doing this repositioning.

I changed this code to implement my own positioning behaviour.